# Get Values of \chapterheadstartvskip from KOMA Script

Tags: koma-script

A colleague of mine asked me about the spacing used in KOMA script's scrreprt, because she would like to use the same spacing in her Word document (no room for discussion here, believe me I tried to convice her to use TeX.)

I understand that these values are stored e.g. in `\chapterheadstartvskip` etc, but how can I access the value of these. I could not find the default values (as far as I can see, the scrreprt class is un-altered) nor was I able to print these values (as you can do e.g. with counters).

Comment: since the measurements for the tex setup are not really comparable (not measuring the same things, typically) a reasonable approach is really just to take a sample document on paper and a real physical ruler and measure things that you want to specify to Word.

Comment: You can find the values in the KOMA script manual (version 2015-11-06) in table 21.5.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the name `\chapterheadstartvskip` is not a skip but a macro, which is defined by defaults as `\vspace{\@tempskipa}`. `\@tempskipa` is calculated inside the chapter command from `\scr@chapter@beforeskip` which depends beside other on the baselineskip (and so the font size of chapter).

The easiest way to get the exact value used in a concrete document is imho to insert a show command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\showthe\@tempskipa\vspace{\@tempskipa}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{abc}
\end{document}
```

and then to check the log-file:

```
> 44.88005pt plus 1.0pt.
\chapterheadstartvskip ->\showthe \@tempskipa
```